# Failed to launch GDB: .pioinit:11: Error in sourced command file: Remote communication error. Target disconnected

Tags: debugging

VSCODE ver#    : 1.75.1
PlatformIO ver#: 3.0.0
GDB ver#       : 12.1

PlatformIO.ini file:
platform       : espressif32
board          : upesy_wroom
framework      : arduino

ESP32 Board connected directly to the PC USB port with no external debug board.  Trying to use the
onboard ESP32 debugger.

I'm using VSCode & PlatformIO to program & debug an ESP32 WRoom Dev Board.  I keep getting this error:
Failed to launch GDB: .pioinit:11: Error in
sourced command file: Remote communication error. Target disconnected.

The debug console displays:
undefinedC:\Users\Joel.platformio\packages\toolchain-xtensa-esp32\bin\xtensa-esp32-elf-gdb.exe: warning: Couldn't determine a path for the index cache directory.

Reading symbols from C:\Users\Joel\Documents\PlatformIO\Projects\BLINK.pio\build\upesy_wroom\firmware.elf...
PlatformIO: debug_tool = cmsis-dap
PlatformIO: Initializing remote target...
Open On-Chip Debugger  v0.11.0-esp32-20220706 (2022-07-06-15:48)
Licensed under GNU GPL v2
WARNING: boards/esp-wroom-32.cfg is deprecated, and may be removed in a future release.
adapter speed: 5000 kHz

Info : tcl server disabled
Info : telnet server disabled
Error: unable to find a matching CMSIS-DAP device

.pioinit:11: Error in sourced command file:
Remote communication error.  Target disconnected.: Success.

I installed the GCC and GDB at this location:  C:\msys64\mingw64\bin

I'm a beginner using VSCode & the ESP32.  I'm trying to follow the examples from the Random Nerd site, and since switching to a new PC, this has been tripping me up.

Any ideas for a fix?
Thanks in advance,
Joel

I tried using 4 different ESP32 boards to make sure it wasn't a hardware problem.

I uninstalled PlatformIO, VSCode, and deleted all project folders.  I re-installed everything and verified the GDB version that is installed:

Answer (score 0):

According to the PlatformIO Board Explorer, all the boards that include the WROOM definition in their names **depend on external debbugers**.
As of today, one (the uPesy ESP32 WROOM DevKit) specifies that the external probe is needed, the other one (the Denky32 (WROOM32)) says that

> Debugging currently does not support Denky32 (WROOM32) board.

The other boards that include WROOM in their names are ESP8266 based.
Seems you'll need an external probe. Good luck!
G.//